# undefined method `symbolize_keys!' for 2:Fixnum

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I am using ruby 1.9.2 and rails 3.  I am getting the following error while running my application.

Error:

```
           undefined method `symbolize_keys!' for 2:Fixnum  line #606 raised:
```

Code: Line number 606

```
         <%= f.text_field :total_amount ,:label=>'Grand Total',:value =>number_with_precision(0,2),:readonly=>true %>
```

Application Trace :

```
 actionpack (3.0.0) lib/action_view/helpers/number_helper.rb:238:in `number_with_precision'

 app/views/cashier/cashier/billing.rhtml:606:in `block (2 levels) in _app_views_cashier_cashier_billing_rhtml__3412897403160140582_59881040__1001215579093570677'

 actionpack (3.0.0) lib/action_view/helpers/capture_helper.rb:39:in `block in capture'

 actionpack (3.0.0) lib/action_view/helpers/capture_helper.rb:171:in `with_output_buffer'

 actionpack (3.0.0) lib/action_view/helpers/capture_helper.rb:39:in `capture'
```

Please help me to correct this error. Thanks in Advance!!!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`number_with_precision` expects the second parameter to be an options hash

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/NumberHelper.html#method-i-number_with_precision

In general, whenever you see "undefined method 'symbolize_keys!'" it means you're passing in some other object or value where Ruby/Rails expects a `Hash`.

Answer (score 0):

putting this here for those who don't use Ruby but see this error when using an API that is coded in Ruby such as Clock Hotel Software. I was posting a JSON string like `{"date":"2013-04-05","value":3}` to it and getting the error. it turned out I was supposed to be posting an array instead: `[{"date":"2013-04-05","value":3}]` corrected the error.

so to expand [aisrael](https://stackoverflow.com/users/878182/aisrael)'s answer, make sure the *type* of what you're giving the program at the other end is what is expected.